# How to access the height of the display area of a beamer presentation, sans header, footer, and navigation strip?

Tags: beamer, dimensions

This question was closed under the pretext that it "needs details or clarity." In my opinion the question is clear, and I don't see what details might be missing. Also the single user who responded to this question did not indicate in her comment that the question was unclear or that details were missing. Therefore I'd appreciate it if those who decided to close this question citing missing details or clarity would explain what details are missing or what is unclear about the question. And if they are not able to do so, the question should be reopened.

---

Consider the following LaTeX code for a simple beamer presentation. The code is saved in the file `presentation.tex`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

After executing `pdflatex presentation` at the command line, a 1-page pdf file is produced.

How can I get the height of the white area indicated with a red double-headed arrow in the screenshot below (which does not include the header, the footer, and the navigation strip)? Is there a command similar to `\textwidth`, `\textheight`, etc. that evaluates to this dimension?

[image: A 1-page beamer presentation]

Comment: There is no such height defined in beamer because then navigations symbols don't occupy space. They are shown in front of the content. If you want to calculate the space, you could measure the height of the navigation symbols and subtract it from the textheight. ... anyway, this very much sounds like an x-y-problem.

Comment: I'm going to hold off on voting, but "sounds like an x-y-problem" is definitely in the realm of "lacking details or clarity".  An x-y-problem is where you're asking us one thing, but are really trying to solve something else.  And often, that something else turns out to be easier to solve than the original question.  So the detail that needs to be filled in is "why do you want to know that height?"

Comment: @Teepeemm I don't remember any more, a year after asking it, if I had an ulterior motive to ask this question, and if so - what it was. Maybe if, back in July, instead of writing "x-y problem" the commenter would have written: "It feels like you're asking us one thing, but are really trying to solve something else. Would you fill in this detail?" I might have been able to respond in an appropriate manner. Having said this, I don't know that I did have an ulterior motive, and the question as-is sounds interesting to me, and clear, and no detail is missing to answer it.

Comment: @EvanAad The missing detail is what the actual problem is you want to solve. There might be alternative approaches for the actual problem, but it is necessary to know what the problem is.